# How to convert a (short) sample in a soundfile to array of bytes

Tags: java

In converting from short to a byte array I found the following solution on the web but could not quite understand the logic involved.

```
//buffer is an array of bytes, bytes[]
buffer[position] = (byte)(sample & 0xff);
buffer[position+1] = (byte)((sample >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Can someone tell me why 0xff (256) is being anded to the sample which is a short?

Answer (score 11):

This code probably comes from C code (or was written by a C programmer who don't parse Java as well as erickson does). This is because in Java a cast from a type with more information to a type with less information will discard the higher order bits and thus the & 0xff is unnecessary in both cases.

A short has 16 bits, two bytes. So it needs to take two slots in the byte array, because if we just casted a short into a byte one byte would be lost.

So, the code you have does

```
1110001100001111 sample
0000000011111111 0xff
0000000000001111 sample & 0xff => first byte`
```

Then, displaces the sample to get the second byte

```
0000000011100011 sample >> 8
0000000011111111 0xff
0000000011100011 (sample >> 8 ) & 0xff => second byte
```

Which can be a lot better written as erickson shows below (hopefully it'll be above soon).

Comment: Great explanation. I was pondering how to best answer, but I'll vote this up instead.

Comment: Excellent answer Vinko! This combined with McWafflestix response below makes a perfect answer.

Comment: Just added the two extra bits (no pun intended) from McWafflestix's answer that weren't here.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have some good information, but unfortunately, they both promote an incorrect idea about the cast to byte.

The `& 0xFF` is unnecessary in both cases in your original code.

A narrowing cast discards the high-order bits that don't fit into the narrower type. In fact, the `& 0xFF` actually first causes the short to be promoted to an `int` with the most significant 24 bits cleared, which is then chopped down and stuffed in a byte by the cast. See the [Java Language Specification Section §5.1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#25363) for details.

```
buffer[position] = (byte) sample;
buffer[position+1] = (byte) (sample >>> 8);
```

Also, note my use of the right shift with zero extension, rather than sign extension. In this case, since you're immediately casting the result of the shift to a byte, it doesn't matter. In general, however, the operators give different results, and you should be deliberate in what you choose.

Comment: Great answer! Good to learn new things from language lawyers :-).

Answer (score 1):

It makes sure there's no overflow; specifically, the first line there is taking the LSByte of "sample" and masking OUT your upper 8 bits, giving you only values in the range of 0-255; the second line there is taking the MSByte of "sample" (by performing the right-shift) and doing the same thing.  It shouldn't be necessary on the second line, since the right-shift by 8 should drop out the 8 least significant bits, but it does make the code a little bit more symmetric.

I would assume that this is because since sample is a short (2 bytes) any values in the range of 256-6553 would be interpreted as 255 by the byte conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer[position] = (byte)(sample & 0xff);
buffer[position+1] = (byte)((sample >> 8) & 0xff);
```

must be :

```
buffer[position] = (byte)((sample >> 8) & 0xff);
buffer[position+1] = (byte)(sample & 0xff);
```